# How do I implement oninput in Jade?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, pug

```
    input(type='range', id= 'inputSlider', min='0', max='255', value='50', step='1', oninput=showValue(this.value))
    span#outputText 50

script.
    var socket = io.connect();

    socket.on('led', function (data) {
    document.getElementById("inputSlider").value = data.value;
    document.getElementById("outputText").innerHTML = data.value;
    });

    function showValue(newValue)
    {
    document.getElementById("outputText").innerHTML=newValue;
    socket.emit('led', { value: newValue });
    }
```

How do I assign a value to the `oninput` attribute in Jade?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you defined the `showValue` function elsewhere, your code should work as long as you put `showValue(this.value)` inside quotes.

```
input(type='range', 
      id= 'inputSlider', 
      min='0', 
      max='255', 
      value='50', 
      step='1', 
      oninput='showValue(this.value)')
```